# Renaming cache tags in API Platform

Tags: varnish, api-platform.com

We are using API Platform with Varnish as proxy.
API Platform returns a Cache-tags header. Unfortunately this header tends to grow in size very fast until it reaches Varnish header size limit.
We can't change the Varnish settings so we are trying to reduce the header size.
We noticed that one entity in particular was filling 90% of the header's content:

- product-attribute-values/210
- product-attribute-values/211
- ...

So I have the idea to rename the cache tag and force all product attributes to use `product-attribute-values` as cache tag. So to be clear: one cache tag for all the product attributes.

Is that possible?
Did anymore encounter this situation?

Thanks